# Prove Big O notation

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, big-o

I am a beginner and taking an online algorithm course, and when I refer a book, I found out the following questions.

1. Given that f(x) = 2x^2 + 5x +3 and g(x) = 2x^3 +x -100, prove f(x) = O(g(x))

   ```
   Let c = 4 and x = 5, 
   2x^2 + 5x +3 <= c(2x^3 +x -100)  
   I tried to solve the left side as follows. 
   if x >=1, then x <=x^3, 5x <= 5x^3 ... 
   2x^2 + 5x +3 => 2x^3 + 5x^3 +3x^3
                => 10x^3
   ```

   My question is can I ignore the -100 of g(x) and compare it with 10x^3 with some value of c?
2. Is it correct to say the run time of the below algorithm is O(n(logn))?

   ```
   int foo(int n){
       int i,j,k=0; 
       for(i = n/2; i <= n; i++){
           for(j = 2; j<= n; j = j * 2){
               k += n/2; 
           } 
       } 
       return k; 
   }
   ```

Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: Please, note that I have a hard time to post the second code and I posted it as a snippet.

Comment: 1) It is actually very misleading to use the definition of big-O directly, since it's easy to become confused by the constants (which of course have no effect); you should consider using a *limit* proof instead. 2) Correct, but show your working.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Thanks for editing the question and for the answer. But, what if I am asked to prove f(x) = O(g(x))? Do I need to ignore the -100?

Comment: you need to ignore every term but the fastest growing (usually)

Comment: One question per question, please.  Your first question is pure math and belongs on [math.se] instead.

Comment: @jwodder I am new and I apologize for doing that.

Comment: No, you can't ignore anything. You'll need to pick the appropriate constant and starting point to take that term into account.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog For formal proofs, you need to consider all terms. You can derive that the smaller terms don't matter based on the proof, but you can't ignore them for the proof itself.

Comment: #1 is easily proved with [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Hôpital%27s_rule), but requires at least an introductory understanding of calculus.